# Training CvSVM to detect humans in images using HOGDescriptor

Tags: c++, opencv, svm

I am new to opencv. I am trying to extract the features of images using HOGDescriptor in opencv. I am trying to train an SVM using Opencv2.2 which would be able to detect humans in images. I am using INRIA training samples containing 614 positives & 1218 negatives.

**Problem:** I am not getting good results. The **accuracy is 70%** when i am testing the SVM with the training samples. Can anyone help me how to adjust the parameters of SVM for unequal negatives & positives.
The parameters for my SVM are:

```
CvMat *m=cvCreateMat(2,1,CV_32FC1);
cvmSet(m,0,0,1);
cvmSet(m,1,0,1);

CvSVMParams params;

params.svm_type = CvSVM::C_SVC;
params.kernel_type = CvSVM::LINEAR;
params.term_crit = cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 100, 1e-6);
params.class_weights=m;
params.C=1000;
```

The entire code for the SVM training is:

void svm_train(char *list)
{
      int num_files=1832;

```
 int features=1620;

  float des;

int val=0;
int file_num=0;
int total=num_files*features;
int count=0;
Mat training_mat(num_files,features,CV_32FC1);
float label[1832];
for(int i=0;i<614;i++)
    label[i]= 1.0;
for(int j=614;j<1832;j++)
    label[j]= -1.0;
Mat labels(num_files,1,CV_32FC1,label);
    char *s;
fstream inputfile(list,ios::in);


while(count<=total)
{  

                if(val<=(features-1))
         {inputfile>>des;

    training_mat.at<float>(file_num,val)= des;
           val++;

        }
        else
        {
            val=0;
            file_num++;

        }
        count++;
}
count--;
cout<<count;




CvMat *m=cvCreateMat(2,1,CV_32FC1);
cvmSet(m,0,0,1);
cvmSet(m,1,0,1);
CvSVMParams params;
params.svm_type=CvSVM::C_SVC;
params.kernel_type = CvSVM::LINEAR;
 params.term_crit   = cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 100, 1e-6);
  params.class_weights=m;

 inputfile.close();
CvSVM svm;
pg=svm.get_default_grid(CvSVM::C);

         params.C=1000;
     fstream filelist("result1.txt",ios::app);
     filelist<<params.C;
     filelist<<"\t1218";
     filelist<<"\t\t614";

     svm.train(training_mat,labels,Mat(),Mat(),params);
     svm.save("svm_train.xml");
    filelist.close();
```

}

Here list is intialised the filename which stores the features extacted from the training samples i.e. negative & positive. The total no. of features for each image= 1620.

Comment: Try a different kernel type?

Comment: I have just 2 classes i.e. humans or not humans so i think i have to use linear kernel only.... Since i dont have equal positive & negative samples that is why i thought i have to set the parameters.... Please help –

Comment: Kernel type doesn't have much to do with the number of possible classes, it has more to do with how the classified examples are distributed. May be linear kernel simply can't divide them well enough. But I agree with the answer, it's more or less try-until-succeed. Playing with the type of kernel is one valid option.

Comment: I actually dont have much idea about the kernel type... If you can explain me what type of kernel can be used,I'll greatly appreciate it. In the opencv documentation also the idea is very vague.

Comment: Just read some docs about support vector machines, for example http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~kathy/cs4701/documents/jason_svm_tutorial.pdf, wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine or something from that page: http://www.kernel-machines.org/tutorials

Comment: In short, linear kernel type is only good if your examples can be separated by a (hyper)line. If not (simplest example: everything inside a circle is one class, everything outside a circle is another class), you have to try nonlinear kernel.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I trained the SVM using RBF Kernel & got an accuracy of 85% in training set. But i would like to know do i have to set class_weights parameter in the SVM??? Will it affect the results??? Would highly appreciate any help

Comment: I used RBF kernel and got the accuracy of 80% in testing samples. I tried to increase the accuracy by adding similar samples which SVM was not able to detect. But instead of improving the accuracy it decreased. Can someone help me what to do as i have to submit this project and i tried a lot but nothing is helping to improve the accutacy???? Please Help...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is hard and fast rule to set the parameters. It is more & less based upon hit and trial under certain limit.

But you should read the following link which is about setting the parameters written by the developers of SVM. It is for not that mathematical...have a look

http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf

Comment: Since i have unequal positive & negative samples so i thought i have to set the parameters...